# Different goo.gl - short urls for same long url

Tags: api, url, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

i want to create a bunch of different short URLs for the same long Url.
I do have a working script (based on the examples given at the API documentation), but it produces always the same short URL for a given (same) long URL.

As authoriziation i do use the API key version.

At this URL

```
https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url/insert#try-it
```

on the right side, you could give it a try.

If you do choose 'Google OAuth 2.0' as Authentication it produces always a different short URL, if you do choose 'API key' it produces always the same.
I do need to use API key, but need to get a different URL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sort of, you cant create unique urls only using the api key. you need to provide an auth key "[..] An auth token is optional for shorten requests. If you provide one, the short URL will be unique, [...]"(https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started)